# Custom Font rendering Ugly (Unreadable)

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using Google open sans custom font and whenever i reload page it render ugly and unreadable

It looks normal when i go inspect elements and uncheck and check the font family again.

I tried to fix it by hosting it on our servers but still no luck, I also used h2, h3,h4 because i thought its a error on h1.

html/css

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700"     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



h2 {
color: rgb(9, 106, 190);
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
text-align: left;
padding-bottom: 5px;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

Anyone know why it is showing like that?

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts of your code into your question.

Comment: Works in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BNZ4s/)

Comment: Reload your fiddle many times and see

Comment: I still cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: @user3801231 I reloaded many times, and it's still the same?

Comment: I fixed it by removing extra custom font installed on page.

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator to generate the Web Fonts and ad them locally

Comment: I accept your answer because this seems more meaningful then other crap in comments!